# 'mvn grails:run-war' unable to deploy war, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: grails, maven

I have created a grails project using the maven integration instructions from the user's guide.  The project builds successfully with 'mvn install' and can be run successfully with 'mvn grails:run-app'.  However, the project can not be run with 'mvn grails:run-war'.

At first, the command 'mvn grails:run-war' appears to function correctly as the command runs successfully and ends with the familiar 'Server running. Browse to '.  However, when you hit the project URL in a browser you get a 404 error and the following output in the tomcat-err.txt.  The same behavior is displayed if an attempt is made to deploy the war file generated from 'mvn install' into tomcat.

Mar 22, 2011 9:03:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Mar 22, 2011 9:03:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0-snapshot
Mar 22, 2011 9:03:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig defaultWebConfig
INFO: No default web.xml
Mar 22, 2011 9:03:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3904)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4456)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:515)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:708)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:286)
        at org.grails.tomcat.IsolatedTomcat.main(IsolatedTomcat.java:101)
Mar 22, 2011 9:03:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3904)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4456)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:515)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:708)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:286)
        at org.grails.tomcat.IsolatedTomcat.main(IsolatedTomcat.java:101)
Mar 22, 2011 9:03:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Mar 22, 2011 9:03:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Mar 22, 2011 9:03:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/fist-gauntlet] startup failed due to previous errors
Mar 22, 2011 9:03:41 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start

Is there a dependency problem in the way mvn builds a grails war file?

Thanks,

Nathan

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading from grails 1.3.6 to grails 1.3.7 resolved the problem

Comment: Just hit this problem and your solution worked for me too - thanks.